# Cron Perl File Gzip Backup

Tags: perl, cron

I'm trying to make a small change to a website which I'm working on. (I can design great looking sites but tech stuff is a little over me so simple answers please...) I didn't create this perl file but want to edit it.

The site has a cron script running daily to back up a db. The cron seems to run a perl file with the command like this (edited) :

```
exec "/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -uxxx -pxxx dbname |gzip > /var/www/db/y$dt.gz";
```

($dt being a date string created earlier)

It works so I don't want to mess with that.

I want to add a line which will gzip backup all the files in a certain folder using the same date technique. I'm guessing :

```
exec "gzip /path/to/image/folder > /var/www/db/f$dt.gz";
```

would work but I don't want to get this wrong.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use 2 commands:

```
exec "tar -cf /var/www/db/f$dt.tar /path/to/image/folder";
exec "gzip /var/www/db/f$dt.tar";
```

The first command makes an archive with the images.  The second command compresses the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU tar, which is the case if on a Linux system, the following
will tar and gzip the folder in a single command:

exec "tar czf /var/www/db/f$dt.tar.gz /path/to/image/folder"